# What is state-of-art of favicons in 2013?

Tags: html, browser, favicon

Favicon business got complicated during last years. New kinds of devices (re)invented, like tablets and smart smartphones. They use favicons in new ways (e.g. as application icons on homescreens) and require vendor-specific ways of linking them. In similar way, browsers now allow creating desktop-shortcuts for web-apps (which also use favicons for icons). Worse, we now have high-resolution ("retina") displays in both portable devices and laptops, which require higher-resolution images for icons. Even worse, different browsers (and versions) support different image-formats for icons and different sizes. Starting with 16x16-only .ico-only IE6 and ending with Opera, which now supports .svg icons.

**What should I do in order to support crisp icons on most devices and browsers of today?**

So far the best resource I could find was [html5boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate), which recommends having the following files:

```
apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png
apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png
apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png
apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png
apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
apple-touch-icon.png
favicon.ico  # 32x32
```

while not putting any links to them in `<head>` tag.

**Edit:** another consideration is that .ico files *can* store several images with different resolution in them. Is this useful or supported?

Answer (score 13):

There is some official advice at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html which seem to confirm your list.

Ideally, the favicon.ico file should contain multiple resolutions in the one file as up to date browsers can now take advantage of this and a 16 x 16 icon is never going to look very good on a retina screen.

Microsoft apparently now recommend the favicon.ico file contain at least 16×16, 24×24, 32×32 and 64×64.

I just launched a free online tool that will create favicons like this at: http://iconifier.net

See the readme page on the website for more links to the latest favicon information.

Comment: Thanks for your tool, i just used it with great success! A "precomposed" option would be great though, so one wouldn't have to manually rename the apple icon files for precomposed icons. Cheers!

Comment: Very helpful tool. It's great. I think however it's quite ironic that you don't use a favicon for the tool.

Comment: @p11y it's not always good to use the non-"precomposed" icons as though they are.  They are meant to be fully composed icons that will look good as an icon on the desktop/home screen; if there's a lot of transparency it might look a bit wrong.  I think Apple devices will compose non-precomposed icons by putting them on a rounded-rectangular background and maybe adding a "gloss" effect.